# Question about complexity of TSP Optimization problem

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, traveling-salesman

Is this statement true?

> Optimization TSP problems are known to be NP-hard, as we do not have a minimum cost to compare against, and in order to verify a solution is optimal, we need to iterate across the solution space.

Answer (score 1):

This statement seems quite vague and confused.

NP-hardness is [precisely defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness#Definition), and you shouldn't loosely say "optimization TSP problems" because it doesn't specify the problem(s). In fact, it is not uncommon that seemingly small changes in a problem lead to different complexities.

Further, because NP-hardness is precisely defined, a problem is not NP-hard because "we do not have a minimum cost to compare against", but because for every problem $X$ in NP there is a polynomial-time reduction to the problem in question - by definition.

Finally, the expression "... to verify a solution is optimal, we need to iterate across the solution space" should be fleshed out more precisely. If the claim is "to verify a solution is optimal, we must inspect every possible solution of the search space", this is wrong.